# What is the best way to declare "string" variables in C #?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, asp.net-core, const-string

I'm a new developer and I have two questions, I researched and it wasn't very clear to me.

What is the difference between using a "string" variable to "String"?

what is the difference between the two examples below

`string my_example = "title (..)";`

to

`const string my_example = "title (..)";`

Comment: difference between examples : the first one can be modified, and second one is constant, it can't be modified.

Comment: A [`const`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) cannot be modified but a regular variable can.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference in the type itself. For String you need a using for namespace System, but not for string.

Same applies to Decimal/decimal, Int32/int, etc. etc.

I always use the lowercase build in c# type where possible (for DateTime you can't)
Microsoft suggests to use the build in types.

Comment: FYI, those are called type aliases.